# A word to describe the state of forgetting something

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe the state one is when forgetting something.

"Forgetful" seems not accurate, as this is more of a general character of not remembering things.

I'm talking about someone who realized he forgot something, and wants to refer to this state. e.g. John realized he forgot something, and wondered how long was he ______ (in the state of forgetting that something).

Does such a word exists?

Comment: You mean like *oblivious*?

Comment: hmmm, yes, this could work. Though oblivious is not only for memory issues. You could be oblivious for not knowing something at all, not just for not remembering something.

Comment: I was thinking of sweet oblivion meaning forgetfulness. Cf oubliette.

Comment: *Forgetfulness*: lapse of memory {https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forgetfulness}

Comment: Unaware? ........

Comment: First, I'm not sure why just saying "I've forgotten" (or "I forgot") isn't appropriate. Second, when you talk about the state, do you mean forgetting and not realizing you've forgotten, or forgetting, knowing you've forgotten, and struggling to remember?

Comment: @JasonBassford either will do. But I don't think there is a word for either. Maybe it's time to invent one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will pick-up where *[tchrist](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist)* left in the comment section. Actually, this word was my primary choice because you were looking for a word expressing *a forgetful state of the mind*.

OP if you dig down into the etymology of the word "Oblivion", the ***primary*** definition of ***oblivion*** (late 14c) is **"state or fact of forgetting"** from Old French *Oblivion* (13c).
https://www.etymonline.com/word/oblivion#etymonline_v_2432

Also, there is always lexical semantics in the play, when we use the word in the given context the word may mean little different, but not far from the *root* meaning. Even here, the word *mean* has different meanings in the given context: 1. *to intend* and 2. *unkind or unpleasant*.

The secondary meaning of the word ***oblivion*** in the contexts is: the state of being completely destroyed **or** the state of being unconscious. I will also recommend you to check the Cambridge Dictionary on the other definitions of the word: Oblivion. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oblivion

The Cambridge dictionary defines *oblivion* as:

> **Oblivion** (noun)
>    :No Memory
>
> *Meaning*: the ***state*** of being ***completely forgotten***:
>
> *Usage*: These toys will be around for a year or two, then fade into **oblivion**.

`John realized he forgot something, and wondered how long was he` *in the* **oblivion**.

Comment: ok, I think you're right and oblivion is probably the best word, and that it's original meaning was probably the state of forgetting, but since then other meanings grew on it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you've completely forgotten something, and it's a systemic problem rather than just a momentary issue, then you are (or were) experiencing [**amnesia**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amnesia):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : loss of memory due usually to brain injury, shock, fatigue, repression, or illness
> **2** : a gap in one's memory
> **3** : the selective overlooking or ignoring of events or acts that are not favorable or useful to one's purpose or position

If shock or fatigue are related, I suppose it could be appropriately used to describe momentary or episodic periods of forgetfulness.

But, generally, this is a term used only after a medical diagnosis, in a similar way to describing somebody as having [*anomic aphasia*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/anomic%20aphasia), *Alzheimer's Disease* or *dementia*. In which case, they could be said to be having "an episode."

---

For the *routine* inability to remember things, I don't think there's a more appropriate single word than just **forget** (or a variation) itself.

But there are several phrases that could be used to describe the situation:

- I was having a lack of recall.
- It's on the tip of my tongue.
- It completely slipped my mind.
- I had a momentary lapse of reason.
- I had a brain fart.
- I *know* it, I just can't *remember* it.
- I'm drawing a blank.
- I'm having a senior moment.

---

A word that can be used to describe a state in which you do something but, later, cannot recall doing it is **fugue**:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : a disturbed state of consciousness in which the one affected seems to perform acts in full awareness but upon recovery cannot recollect the acts performed

People can also talk about *losing time* or having *blackouts*.

More casual, and figurative, references to this type of thing include the word *sleepwalking* and the phrase *on autopilot*.

Answer (score 0):

With limited context, I would suggest **forgetfulness**.

As in:

John realized he forgot something, and wondered again how long was this episode of his **[forgetfulness](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/forgetfulness)** going to last.

> tendency to forget